# How can I use generics in a function returned from a factory function that is typed?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have defined a type for a factory function where one of the functions returned uses a generic.

```ts
type Factory = (param: string) => {
  func: <T extends {}>(param: string) => Promise<T>,
};

const factory: Factory = __factoryParam => ({
  func: async <T>(__param) => {
    return Promise.resolve({} as T);
  },
});
```

When I hover over the `__param` parameter in the code above I get the error **Parameter '__param' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)**.

If I get rid of the generic, then `__param` is typed correctly. If I explicitly type the parameter in the implementation, it of course works:

```ts
func: async <T>(__param: string) => {
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please use `T extends Record<string, unknown>` instead of `T extends {}`. Please keep in mind that `{}` correspond to any value, almost like `any`. See this: `type Test = number extends {}  ? true : false // true`. This is because everything in javascript is an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where it's fine to use `as any` on the return value and just omit the generic in the implementation:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgY2AewE4igXigCjHVOAWwC4oBnYVASwDsBzASiwD4oBvAWACgooAzAK60EZADwAVKBAAewCLQAm5DgF8WeAsTKUaDZpjYAFVMiLVyESSwA0PVQG4ePBMlqUBiFOjLwkaDGwAfSD+LwCjLSJWXC5eKDhyEBEBYQRcEPxCImY4vj5UCGBBVFooEzMLCAA6QvJkABsANwgcdlVmRITaECd41TtuDr6XNw86wQbgLE9-dBwAcl0FxmqhETF2InJ6MgWACwgGhuQF9UXdACYVhygAejvy03NLTaht3agDo5OFqHUgA)

```ts
type Factory = (param: string) => {
  func: <T extends {}>(param: string) => Promise<T>,
};

const factory: Factory = __factoryParam => ({
  async func (__param) {
    return Promise.resolve({}) as any;
  },
});

const result = factory('str').func<{msg: 'hello'}>('str2'); // Promise<{ msg: 'hello' }>
```